# Approach for classifying job description sentences

Tags: python, r, nlp, text-classification, topic-modeling

I need to classify/categorize the various sentences in the `job_experience` section of n=630 job descriptions. I'm particularly interested in extracting the work experience and ability-related sentences, but I need to be able keep them attached to the `job_title` that they are associated with.

**Current state of these job descriptions:** many different ways of saying similar things (e.g., "Needs Microsoft Office skills." "Experience using Microsoft Word, PowerPoint." "Minimum 3 years experience in related field." "Minimum three years experience in similar role.").

**In the future**, we will need to condense these job description statements so that, for example, the same statement can be applied to multiple jobs, and where managers select from a drop-down list of job experience statements.

So I would like to categorize these individual sentences so that we can begin condensing them and deciding on which statements will be used going forward.

I've been researching what I should do and **I would appreciate any suggestions on which approach will be the most efficient.** I am familiar with R but use it mostly for data wrangling and visualization. LDA, kmeans text clustering, feature identification... these are the things I'm finding in my research (scikit-learn.org) and mostly with application in Python.

- Is Python best for this kind of thing? Can I use R?
- Which algorithmic approach is best for a beginner?
- I know this isn't magic - just looking for the best approach to this task.

My data looks like:

```
df <- data.frame(job_title = c("Recruiter","Recruiter","Recruiter","Recruiter",
                         "File Clerk","File Clerk",
                         "Learning & Org. Development Specialist","Learning & Org. Development Specialist","Learning & Org. Development Specialist","Learning & Org. Development Specialist",
                         "CNA","CNA","CNA"),
           job_experience = c("Minimum 1 year experience in recruitment or related human resources function.",
                              "Proficient in Microsoft Office Applications.",
                              "High school diploma required.",
                              "Bachelors Degree in Human Resources or related field preferred.",
                              "High School diploma preferred.",
                              "Ability to use relevant computer systems.",
                              "Bachelors Degree in related field (e.g., Human Resources, Education, Organizational Development).",
                              "Minimum 2 years experience applying L&OD principles and practices in an organizational setting.",
                              "Previous work experience in Human Resources preferred.",
                              "Experience with a learning management system (LMS).",
                              "High school diploma or GED equivalent.",
                              "Certified Nursing Assistant, certified by the Virginia Board of Health Professions.",
                              "CPR certification required at date of hire."))
```

My goal is to have a dataset like this (new column = `job_exp_category`):

```
job_title  job_experience                               job_exp_category
"Recruiter"  "Minimum 1 year experience in recruitment..."  "Work experience"
"Recruiter"  "Proficient in Microsoft Office Applicati..."  "Skill/Ability"
"Recruiter"  "High school diploma required."                "Degree"
...          ...                                            ...   
"CNA"        "Certified Nursing Assistant, certificati..."  "Certification/License"
"CNA"        "CPR certification required at date of hire."  "Certification/License"
```

Thank you for any insight SO community.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone sees this post and has a similar need, here is what I (OP) ended up doing:

Following [the content in this link](https://cfss.uchicago.edu/notes/supervised-text-classification/), I used a combination of supervised learning (random forest) to classify the job description statements into four categories (degree, work experience, certification/license, and ksa) and unsupervised learning (kmeans cluster analysis) to bucket work experience statements that used similar words (e.g., cluster 1 = statements that referenced Microsoft office products).

The general process included:

**PHASE 1 (identify work experience-related job description statements):**

- hand-coding a sample of the job description statements into the appropriate category
- converting my data set to a `tidytext` dataframe that would prepare it for analysis
- create a training data set using the hand-coded job descriptions statements with their associated categories, then creating a test data set that contained the to-be-categorized job description statements
- estimating a random forest model (supervised learning) using the `caret` package [ details: `method="ranger"`, out-of-box resampling method, number of trees = 200]. My OOB prediction error was 2.96%.
- used `predict()` to predict the job description categories on the remaining data (i.e., test data set)

**PHASE 2 (classify work experience statements into related buckets):**

- being comfortable with my prediction error for this task, I filtered to include only the job description statements that fell under 'work experience'
- after cleaning the data set to avoid clustering on non-important words (e.g., *preferred*) I used `kmeans()` cluster analysis (k = 200) to bucket the work experience statements into clusters based on the words used.

At this point, we're still ultimately deciding what the final work experience descriptions/categorizations will be, but this process is now more efficient with the trimmings gone and a bit of a head start on how to categorize appropriately.